# Blazor web assembly send data in every request

Tags: c#, blazor, identityserver4, access-token, blazor-webassembly

I'm creating an application with Blazor web assembly and IdentityServer4.
When the user logs, selects a company, and I store it (I already have this part), but I need to share that company with the controller (to check permissions and access to data).

How can I do that, or should I send the company selected and the user in every request?

Comment: You need to show more of a code example so we can give you specific assistance, prehpas by showing code on how the client resolves the selection. In general if personalization or other user or account centric data is stored, then the server should be able to retrieve that information based on the authenticated user. If the selection is more transient, as in you don't want to store it permanently then you could pass it back to the server via HTTP headers on each request. Many apps use a combination of these techniques. Please re-focus your post to either of these concepts.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar with a `IProfileService`. You need to add the company information as a claim.

```
    public class IdentityProfileService : IProfileService
    {

        private readonly IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> _claimsFactory;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public IdentityProfileService(IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> claimsFactory, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _claimsFactory = claimsFactory;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
        {
            var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("User not found!",nameof(user));
            }

            var principal = await _claimsFactory.CreateAsync(user);
            var claims = principal.Claims.ToList();

            //Add more claims like this
            //claims.Add(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("MyProfileID", user.Id));

            context.IssuedClaims = claims;
        }

        public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
        {
            var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
            context.IsActive = user != null;
        }
    }
```

Startup.cs

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    ...
})
    .AddConfigurationStore<ConfigurationDbContext>(options =>
    {
       ...
    })    
    .AddOperationalStore<PersistedGrantDbContext>(options =>
    {
        ...
    })
    .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddProfileService<IdentityProfileService>();   // <=========
```

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for something like this, but testing it... It doesn't fit well for what I need (so I think), the user should be able to change from one company to other (if authorized in multiple), so he should be able to change the claims on runtime and I haven't found the way of doing it (I don't know if it's possible)

Comment: @Raykler You could add multiple claims and a landing page for users that do..